# JDialog with scrollable objects

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am using an object of components then calling in Jdialog but I want to make it scrollable as due to more number of components it's taking enough space in the screen. I found many solutions for textarea scrolling but not any relevant for me.

```
//Object of components
             Object[] Payments = {
            "For Max-cost 14 (Applied to all currencies):", er1,
            "For Max-cost 12 (Applied to all currencies)", er2,
            "For Max-cost 10.5 (Applied to all currencies)",er105,
            "For Max-cost 10 (Applied to all currencies)", er10,                                    
            "For Max-cost 9 (Applied to all currencies)", er9,                                   
            "For Max-cost 8.25 (Applied to all currencies)",er825,
            "For Max-cost 8 (Applied to all currencies)", er8,                                   
            "For Max-cost 7 (Applied to all currencies)", er7,                        
            "For Max-cost 6.75 (Applied to all currencies)",er675,
            "For Max-cost 6 (Applied to all currencies)", er3,
            "For Max-cost 5 (Applied to all currencies)", er6,            
            "For Max-cost 4 (Applied to all currencies)", er4,
            "For Max-cost 3.75 (Applied to all currencies)",er375,
        };
//calling dialog 
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, Payments, "Set Amount for different job-budget", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Comment: You can use JScrollPane for this

Comment: Refer this link. https://alvinalexander.com/java/joptionpane-showmessagedialog-example-scrolling

Comment: Add all the components to a panel. Pass the panel to the scroll pane constructor. Add the scroll pane to the dialog (or a panel in the dialog).

Comment: *I am using an object of components* - that is not an object of components, that is an array of strings. I would suggest you could create a JList of all the Stings. Then you just add the JList to a JScrollPane. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for examples to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

this can be help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScrollDialog dialog = new ScrollDialog();
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}

public static class ScrollDialog extends JDialog {
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private JPanel innerPane = new JPanel();

    public ScrollDialog() {
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.innerPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 800));
        this.scrollPane.setViewportView(innerPane);
    }
}
```

add what you want in "innerPane". Be Happy Coding :)